# How resolve $y''+y=\sin(x)$ by power series around the point $x_0=0$

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, analysis

The ODE I tried to solve is:
$$y''+y=\sin(x)$$
using the power series method around the point $x_0=0$, with the conditions:
$$y(0)=0,\qquad y'(0)=0$$

Let
\begin{align}
y(x) &= \sum_{n=0}^{\infty} a_{n} \, x^n \\
y^{'}(x) &= \sum_{n=0}^{\infty} (n+1) \, a_{n+1} \, x^n \\
y^{''}(x) &= \sum_{n=0}^{\infty} (n+1)(n+2) \, a_{n+2} \, x^n.
\end{align}
then the differential equation gives
\begin{align}
\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} (n+1)(n+2) \, a_{n+2} \, x^n + \sum_{n=0}^{\infty} a_{n} \, x^n &= \sin(x) \\
\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} ( (n+1)(n+2) \, a_{n+2} + a_{n} ) \, x^n &= \sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \frac{(-1)^n \, x^{2n+1}}{(2 n +1)!}.
\end{align}

I got stuck in this last line, there I see that the sums on both sides are not very identical. So I want to know what change of variable I could apply to the index $n$ in order to find the values of $a_n$. Thanks.

Comment: You have to solve the homogeneous DE first. $y_h=A \cos x +B \sin x$

Comment: Thanks. And then what would I have to do?

Comment: What happens is that they have asked me to solve that differential equation with the power series method, not with the parameter variance method, nor with the undetermined coefficients method.

Comment: This is a different task then.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The difficulty as stated in the work of the proposed problem the left-hand side should be broken into even and odd index to match the right-hand side. Doing so gives the desired recurrence equations and thus solution.

This solution takes a similar but different path. Let
$$ y(x) = \sum_{n=0}^{\infty} a_{n} \, x^n $$
which leads to
\begin{align}
y(x) &= \sum_{n=0}^{\infty} a_{n} \, x^n \\
y^{'}(x) &= \sum_{n=0}^{\infty} (n+1) \, a_{n+1} \, x^n \\
y^{''}(x) &= \sum_{n=0}^{\infty} (n+1)(n+2) \, a_{n+2} \, x^n.
\end{align}
Now, by using
$$ \sin(x) = \frac{e^{i x} - e^{-i x}}{2 i} = \sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \frac{i^{n-1} \, (1 - (-1)^n)}{2 \, n!} \, x^n, $$
the differential equation becomes
\begin{align}
y^{''} + y &= \sin(x) \\
\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \left( (n+1)(n+2) \, a_{n+2} + a_{n} \right) \, x^n &= \sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \frac{i^{n-1} \, (1-(-1)^n)}{2 \, n!} \, x^n 
\end{align}
which gives the recurrence
$$ a_{n+2} = - \frac{a_{n}}{(n+1)(n+2)} + \frac{i^{n-1} \, (1-(-1)^n)}{2 \, (n+2)!}. $$
From this is can be seen that when $n$ is even the term with $1 - (-1)^n$ is zero and leads to
$$ a_{2n} = - \frac{a_{0}}{(2 n)!}. $$
The odd values take the form
\begin{align}
a_{1} &= a_{1} \\
a_{3} &= \frac{1}{3!} - \frac{a_{1}}{3!} \\
a_{5} &= - \frac{2}{5!} + \frac{a_{1}}{5!} \\
a_{7} &= \frac{3}{7!} - \frac{a_{1}}{7!} \\
\cdots &= \cdots
\end{align}
This leads to
$$ y(x) = - a_{0} \, \cos(x) - a_{1} \, \sin(x) - \frac{x \, \cos(x)}{2}. $$
Applying the initial conditions $y(0) = y^{'}(0) = 0$ gives
$$ y(x) = \frac{\sin(x) - x \, \cos(x)}{2}. $$

Comment: Thank you very much, your contribution is very useful to me. Although so far I don't know how $\frac{x\cdot\cos(x)}{2}$ appears from that recursion formula.